# "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-5

Error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_UserProfile_UserLogin". The conflict occurred in database
>   "ToDoDB", table "dbo.UserLogin", column 'UserLoginID'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

What could this mean?

I am trying to build a simple log in and profile `MVC5` web app. I created my table in SQL Express.

Firstly here is my model for the sign up page:

```
public class UserSignUp
{
    [Key]
    public int UserLoginID { get; set; }

    //Foregin key for the login table - First name, last name, creation date, and email
    public int UserProfileID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Valid email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So the `UserLoginID` is the primary key from the `UserLogin` table and the `UserProfileID` is the primary from the `UserProfile` table. I set the foreign key of the `UserProfile` table to `UserLoginID` from the `UserLogin`.

Here is my model for creating a new user:

```
public class UserProfileManager
{
    public void AddUserAccount(UserSignUp newUser)
    {
        // create database connection
        using (ToDoDBEntities db = new ToDoDBEntities())
        {
            // Collect viewmodel data
            // Here building goes by object type and not foregin key relationship
            UserLogin UL = new UserLogin();
            UL.Username = newUser.Username;
            UL.Password = newUser.Password;

            // Add the UserLogin object I just built to the database
            db.UserLogins.Add(UL);
            db.SaveChanges();

            UserProfile UP = new UserProfile();
            // establish connection to UL by establishing foreign key relationship
            UP.UserLoginID = newUser.UserLoginID;
            UP.FirstName = newUser.FirstName;
            UP.LastName = newUser.LastName;
            UP.CreationDate = newUser.CreationDate;
            UP.Email = newUser.Email;

            // Add UserProfile object to databse and save changes
            db.UserProfiles.Add(UP);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    //Check if user is real before login is allowed
    public bool isLoginReal(string LoginName)
    {
        using (ToDoDBEntities DB = new ToDoDBEntities())
        {
            // Return the user from the DB whose login name matches the LoginName string passed in as perameter
            return DB.UserLogins.Where(o => o.Username.Equals(LoginName)).Any();
        }
    }
}
```

My `AddUserAccount` is where I think I am having issues. So I start by building the `UserLogin` object and adding and saving to the database. That seems to work out actually. But the next step where I build, add, and save the `UserProfile` object doesn't seem to work. At least the database doesn't get updated.

Here is the controller handling the actions:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // GET: Account
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    #region signup methods
    // Get method for signup page
    public ActionResult SignUpPage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Post method for signup page - post to db
    [HttpPost]
    // Pass in the UserSign up model object to be built
    public ActionResult SignUpPage(UserSignUp USUV)
    {
        // Form is filled out and then method is entered
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Form is filled out and database connection is established if form is valid
            UserProfileManager UPM = new UserProfileManager();

            if (!UPM.isLoginReal(USUV.Username))
            {
                // data access . adduseraccount from entity manager (where model objects are built)
                UPM.AddUserAccount(USUV);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(USUV.FirstName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

To my (noob) eye everything looks good. The `SignUpPage` is received, then a new `UserSignUp` object is passed into the `Post` action, and entity framework object (`UserProfileManager`) is built, the form is authenticated and the user gets either redirected to the `Welcome` view or the user gets returned to the signup view.

Any chance someone can help me figure out what I am either missing or doing wrong? I included a picture of the database design for reference (I know even less about database then MVC).

[image: Database design]

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on the first line of AddUserAccount() to make sure newUser has values?

Comment: Ok now its giving me an error:                                                                             "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserProfile_UserLogin". The conflict occurred in database "ToDoDB", table "dbo.UserLogin", column 'UserLoginID'.
The statement has been terminated"                                                           What could this mean?

Comment: Put a break point before the second `db.SaveChanges()` and check if the `UP.UserLoginID` has correct value.

Comment: Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, CreationDate, and Email all have correct values. UserLogin is showing as 0. But it should be 1 right? If its the first item to be input in the DB? I have both of those tables set with incrementing (1.1) primary keys. And the userprofile table has UserLoginID set as a foreign key. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did the first `db.SaveChanges()` succeed? After the first `db.SaveChanges()`, is there any record in your `UserLogin` table?

Comment: Yes it did. I have attempted to get this to work and both times the SaveChanges() for the UserLogin table worked. Just not the UserProfile

Comment: Check my answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, after the problem is here:

```
UP.UserLoginID = newUser.UserLoginID;
```

It's not `newUser`, it should be:

```
UP.UserLoginID = UL.UserLoginID;
```

Because you just added the object `UL` to the database, to get the generated ID of the inserted object, you have to call it, not the `newUser` object.

Comment: youre amazing. That was it after all. Thank you so much. The DB did fully update but now I am getting a HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized. It wont redirect to the "Welcome" view. Is that because of the [authorize] annotation I have for the "Welcome" view?

Comment: Yes, double check your authentication process :)

Comment: I wish I could give you a million upvotes. Now I just need to figure out how to add another table to my database and all the correlating controls with it

Comment: Thanks. Happy to help :D